# What is the best way to get all NFT metadata for a NFT specific collection on NEAR?

Tags: nft, nearprotocol

Is there any ready-to-go solution on the near ecosystem?

Should I query the contract for all metadata?

Should I run indexer and get data from events?

I just want to store NFT metadata in the database in the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an RPC call (https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts#call-a-contract-function) to the NFT contract which you are interested in.

To get the data about the collection you can call `nft_metadata` (https://nomicon.io/Standards/Tokens/NonFungibleToken/Metadata)

To get all nfts from the collection you can call `nft_tokens` (https://nomicon.io/Standards/Tokens/NonFungibleToken/Enumeration).

`nft_tokens` takes from_index and limit as args so make sure to use them if you are querying data from a bigger collection. To use this as a regular pagination you can check how many NFTs are out there by querying `nft_total_supply`.

If you want to do this action and update the database from time to time you could set up a cron job or just manually run a script whenever you feel like it.

If you want your database to be always up to date without you having to do anything manually you can use NEAR Lake Indexer (https://near-indexers.io/) or Pagoda Console Alerts (https://console.pagoda.co/) and listen to `nft_mint`. If you also wish to track and have current information about the owner of the NFT you should also listen to `nft_transfer` and update your database to show that there is a new owner of the NFT.

You can also get some data (collection metadata, single nft information, single nft history) from the Pagoda Developer Console by using the NEAR Enhanced API. You won't be able to get information about all nfts in the collection using that API.

I hope this helps.